# Can't start dotnet core process. Failed to add tools

Tags: c#, batch-file, iis, .net-core

I have a web application running in IIS that is starting a process with a .cmd file. The .bat file starts a dotnet core application.

This works fine on my local installation but when I deploy on a server I get the following error:

> Failed to add 'C:\Users\Default.dotnet\tools' to the PATH environment
> variable. Add this directory to your PATH to use tools installed with
> 'dotnet tool install'.

dotnet core and dotnet core sdk are installed. It works fine on the server if I run the .cmd file from a command prompt.

I have searched and can't find any hints on how to solve this.

```
      private void RunMyCmd(string runMyCmdPath)
        {
            int exitCode;
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
            Process process;

            processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(runMyCmdPath);
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // *** Redirect the output ***
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            process = Process.Start(processInfo);

            StreamWriter writer = process.StandardInput;
            //string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
            writer.WriteLine("a");

            // Write the redirected output to this application's window.
            //  Console.WriteLine(output);
            string output1 = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            process.WaitForExit();

            // *** Read the streams ***
            // Warning: This approach can lead to deadlocks, see Edit #2


            exitCode = process.ExitCode;

            if (exitCode != 0)
                errorLogger.Error(string.Format("RunMyCmd: ExitCode({0}) - {1}", exitCode, error));

            process.Close();

        }
```

Edit: .cmd-file code:

```
@echo off
rem switch to on to test
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
rem echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
rem echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
rem echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
rem  Go to script's directory
cd %~dp0

rem  Read filenames if needed
set rules=%~dp0rules.json
set testcases=%~dp0testcases.csv

if not exist %rules% (
    echo file not found. Type in full file name and Enter
    set /p rules="Rules file: "
)
if not exist %rules% (
    echo We did not find rules file: %rules%
    exit /B 1
)

if not exist %testcases% (
    echo testcases not found. Type in full file name and Enter
    set /p testcases="Testcases file: "
)
if not exist %testcases% (
    echo We did not find testcase file: %testcases%
    exit /B 1
)

rem Create filename for results csv
set filename="results_%fullstamp%.csv"
rem Run
cd AppFolder
dotnet run --no-build %rules% %testcases% %filename%
move %filename% ../results/
PAUSE
```

Problem solved.

I installed the Web application on another server and got the following exception:
`Failed to add 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dotnet\tools' to the PATH environment variable. Add this directory to your PATH to use tools installed with 'dotnet tool install'.`
Because I got 2 similar exceptions I figured the problem might be with permissions on the folder.
So I added modify permissions for the service account to the folder
`C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile`
Which solved the problem. After running the app these new folders was created:
`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.dotnet`
`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.nuget`

I then added the same permissions on my prod server but for the folder
`C:\Users\Default`

The question that remains is why two servers are locating .dotnet folders in different paths?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues), especially "The .NET Core CLI tries to add the default location to the PATH environment variable...."

Comment: You should also include the code which defines your `.cmd` file, and preferably provide its content. If you're not willing to do that, please remove the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, in its current state, it is irrelevant, because it is not referenced anywhere.

Comment: What is the string assigned to `runMyCmdPath`? and what is the working directory at the time you invoke it? Also why are you using a batch file to generate the date/time stamps, when it can be done natively within .NET? _(and the same question for checking the existence of a file? requesting input? running an executable file with arguments? and moving a file?)_.

Comment: You cannot install .NET Core Global tool under your account https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues#executable-file-not-found and expect that to work for all users (like the application pool identity). Modify your batch file to install the tool if not detected for that user account.

Comment: The problem is that your tools are not installed, or the installation path is incorrect.

Comment: Problem solved.

I installed the Web application on another server and got the following exception:
`Failed to add 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dotnet\tools' to the PATH environment variable. Add this directory to your PATH to use tools installed with 'dotnet tool install'.`
Because I got 2 similar exceptions I figured the problem might be with permissions on the folder.
So I added modify permissions for the service account to the folder
`C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile`
Which solved the problem. After running the app these new folders was created:

Answer (score 2):

Got similar issue after I renamed my core application dll. Figured my application DLL isn't being found for activation anymore. So i checked inside `web.config` turns out forgot to rename dll.

`dotnet` itself should not be writing any files to C:\Users\Default.dotnet\tools, so the permissions should not be necessary provided the application can be found.